# MYSQL - Not outputting correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have another error at my feet, and this is to create a page for each row of data in a MYSQL database.
The code lies here: http://pastebin.com/rmWbJhVm
Even though it uses the exact same output methods (well, except it's not in a while loop) as http://bobcraft-games.com/TSL/, I don't see why it is messing up.
All mysql information is correct.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The url pattern *http://bobcraft-games.com/TSL/page.php?**id=1*** shows that you are passing an `id` as GET parameter.
But instead you are fetching parameter named `page` as in `$page = $_GET['page']`.

So,

1. Change it to `$page = $_GET['id']`.
2. Change `mysql_real_escape_string($page, $conn)` to `$page = mysql_real_escape_string($page, $conn)` too.

Comment: Thank you! I often forget these things due to my novice brain. It works perfectly.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't even notice that and then read your reply lol.

Answer (score 0):

On line **26** you're not storing the result returned by mysql_real_escape_string() anywhere. Change it to this:

```
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($page, $conn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - But it still doesn't work! It hasn't changed anything on the page.